# Finding out what Infozip's unzip is complaining about

Tags: python-3.x, zip

### Background

I have an application that generates files that *should* be in Zip format, PKZIP version 6.3.3 to be exact. (For the curious: [SIARD 2.0](http://www.eark-project.com/resources/specificationdocs/32-specification-for-siard-format-v20))

### Sample File

I have uploaded a sample file to Google Drive:
[`sample.siard`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IQqxJX-iORdbmtYIVbLbJcUTsmIOCmyi)

### Problem

When I point Infozip's `unzip` under Linux at the file, it complains:

```
testing: content/                 OK
testing: content/schema0/         OK
testing: content/schema0/table0/   OK
testing: content/schema0/table0/table0.xml
 error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
...
```

The same error is given for all actual files. (Not directories)

Verbose file listing (`unzip -v file`) gives:

```
...
6064  Defl:F     1868  69% 2018-01-30 10:41 055f9f61  content/schema0/table0/table0.xml
...
```

(no errors here)

### Infozip version

I have a  reasonable new version of Infozip. `unzip -v` gives

```
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/ ;
see ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 4.9.2 for Unix (Linux ELF) on Jan 28 2017.

UnZip special compilation options:
    ACORN_FTYPE_NFS
    COPYRIGHT_CLEAN (PKZIP 0.9x unreducing method not supported)
    SET_DIR_ATTRIB
    SYMLINKS (symbolic links supported, if RTL and file system permit)
    TIMESTAMP
    UNIXBACKUP
    USE_EF_UT_TIME
    USE_UNSHRINK (PKZIP/Zip 1.x unshrinking method supported)
    USE_DEFLATE64 (PKZIP 4.x Deflate64(tm) supported)
    UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: UTF-8] (handle UTF-8 paths)
    LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
    ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
    USE_BZIP2 (PKZIP 4.6+, using bzip2 lib version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010)
    VMS_TEXT_CONV
    WILD_STOP_AT_DIR
    [decryption, version 2.11 of 05 Jan 2007]
```

The only thing listed as NOT supported is `unreducing`, but that shouldn't be relevant.

When I try Python's `zipfile` module, it both tests and extracts with no problem.  I have also heard that PKZIP itself have no problem with these files, but I personally don't have that installed.

So, I have no problem using these files myself, but they are intended for long time archiving and I really need to know:

### The question

**Is there a way for me to find out if there is a bug in the generation of these files or is there a bug in `unzip`'s handling of them?**

### ZIP64?

I have searched the web and found a lot of people having problem with large files and Zip64 format. However, my files are *not large*. (up to 20Mb uncompressed)

Also, this version of `unzip` should support Zip64. (See version info above)

### Tools

My preferred tools are Python, hex editors and the `bash` command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer.
My subject line was

> Finding out what Infozip's unzip is complaining about

The answer to that turned out to require downloading the source code to `unzip`, add a lot of debug messages, and read them.

In this particular case, `unzip` was complaining about the fact that the zip file used post-file data descriptors without setting the header flag to indicate it. (General flag 3)

Normally one should set this flag **and** set the header CRC/length fields to all zeros.

This file *did not* have the flag set but still the fields were set to zero.  `unzip` then thinks "Oh, the length really must be zero!"

Then the actual non-zero file appears and `unzip` gets all grumpy. The post-file data descriptor did not help.

In the body of the question I asked:

> **Is there a way for me to find out if there is a bug in the generation of these files or is there a bug in `unzip`'s handling of them?**

I personally think these files are broken.  I haven't talked to the people responsible for generating them, but think I have a good case that they have done bad.

On a more philosophical note:

There are two schools on how unzippers should work.

One is the "best effort" school, which says that the program should do whatever it can to recover the files inside regardless of how wrong the formatting is.  (There are obviously limits to this)

The other school is the "Not my problem" school of thought that says that if the zip file is in a wrong format, then the unzipper shouldn't touch it.  Let the makers of the zipfile fix *their* problem instead.

Pkware itself is firmly in the first school of thought, while Infozip is in the second.

Answer (score 1):

On face value, the message "*invalid compressed data to inflate*", suggests your zip file is corrupt. Are you certain that the exact same file can be read successfully with PKZIP, but cannot with Infozip?

After a (very) quick glance at the SIARD standard, it looks like it just uses bog-standard zip files with deflate/store compression. That means that the zip file won't have used a feature that only PKZIP can handle.

One possibility is that the archive has been created with Zip64 extensions, but your version of Infozip doesn't support it.

If you run `unzip -v` it should print a line containing the string  `ZIP64_SUPPORT` if it does.

For reference, this is what I get

```
$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/ ;
see ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) for Unix (Linux ELF) on Feb 25 2015.

UnZip special compilation options:
        COPYRIGHT_CLEAN (PKZIP 0.9x unreducing method not supported)
        SET_DIR_ATTRIB
        SYMLINKS (symbolic links supported, if RTL and file system permit)
        TIMESTAMP
        UNIXBACKUP
        USE_EF_UT_TIME
        USE_UNSHRINK (PKZIP/Zip 1.x unshrinking method supported)
        USE_DEFLATE64 (PKZIP 4.x Deflate64(tm) supported)
        UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: UTF-8] (handle UTF-8 paths)
        MBCS-support (multibyte character support, MB_CUR_MAX = 6)
        LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
        ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
        USE_BZIP2 (PKZIP 4.6+, using bzip2 lib version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010)
        VMS_TEXT_CONV
        [decryption, version 2.11 of 05 Jan 2007]

UnZip and ZipInfo environment options:
           UNZIP:  [none]
        UNZIPOPT:  [none]
         ZIPINFO:  [none]
      ZIPINFOOPT:  [none]
```

To check if you zip file uses Zip64, check the final 6 bytes of the zip file. If the first 4 are all 0xFF (this is the *Offset to Central Dir* field), it is very likely you have a Zip64 archive. Note that this will not work if your zip file has a comment.

For reference, below is a dump from a zip file that uses Zip64. Note the value of the *Offset to Central Dir* field is **FFFFFFFF**

```
10000020C 000000004 50 4B 05 06 END CENTRAL HEADER    06054B50
100000210 000000002 00 00       Number of this disk   0000
100000212 000000002 00 00       Central Dir Disk no   0000
100000214 000000002 04 00       Entries in this disk  0004
100000216 000000002 04 00       Total Entries         0004
100000218 000000004 DA 00 00 00 Size of Central Dir   000000DA
10000021C 000000004 FF FF FF FF Offset to Central Dir FFFFFFFF
100000220 000000002 00 00       Comment Length        0000
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this was not it. I have added version info to the question, sorry about not doing that from the beginning.  Also, the file contains no FF bytes at all. +1 for effort. :)

Comment: Correction. No 'FF' bytes, but plenty 'ff' bytes. (duh)  There *is* ZIP64 info in the file, but my version of unzip should handle it.

Comment: OK. Next question - is this a problem with all SIARD files or just this one? If there are any example files available I can take a look.

Comment: Just noticed in your update. You have shown USE_DEFLATE64. That isn't the one - check if it has ZIP64_SUPPORT.

Comment: Editted again to add more version info. (Perhaps I should just have added the whole thing) The only thing you have that I don't have is MBCS-support.

Comment: Looked at the changelog for the latest beta of the infozip unzip program. There is an issue fixed that mentions a very rare issue with inflating that can cause errors. If the SIARD file is publically  SIARD files available I can try reading it with the beta unzip.